# syntax to use `data-toggle` and `data-target` in link_to rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have:

`<%= link_to :action=>'view_score_card',:id=>innings1_batting_datail.id,remote: true,:class=>"body_inner_icon" do %>`

In this link i want to use `data-toggle="modal"` and `data-target="#myModal1"`.Please tell me the right syntax for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are `link_to` signatures:

```
link_to(body, url, html_options = {})
link_to(body, url_options = {}, html_options = {})
link_to(options = {}, html_options = {})
link_to(url, html_options = {})
```

You want them to end up in html_options block. Try:

```
<%= link_to 'link', {:action => 'view_score_card', :id => innings1_batting_datail.id}, {:remote => true, :class => "body_inner_icon", 'data-target' => "#myModal1", 'data-toggle' => "modal"} do %>
```

Or:

```
<%= link_to 'link', view_score_card_path(innings1_batting_datail), {:remote => true, :class => "body_inner_icon", 'data-target' => "#myModal1", 'data-toggle' => "modal"} do %>
```

Comment: data-target and data-toggle is append with the url............its not the right syntax

Comment: Try changing the order. This is what I use in my project and it works: `<%= link_to "Create new account", "#signup", 'data-target' => "#frmModal-signup", 'data-toggle' => "modal", 'data-dismiss' => "modal" %>`

Comment: This syntax also works: `link_to("", {controller: 'stories', action: 'index', remote: true}, {class: "body_inner_icon", 'data-target' => "#myModal1", 'data-toggle' => "modal"})`